# Configuration Properties are not read by Spring boot when setting properties like this "export my_variable=something"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

edit: please pay close attention to the question. **I want to make changes without having to rebuild and redeploy the application. I want to make changes on the fly.**

I have a simple Spring boot application where I am trying to test if an application can read environment variable without having to rebuild and redeploy the application.

I have a simple main class which is also a `@RestController`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableScheduling
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Value("${taco.orders.pageSize}")
    private String pageSize;

    @GetMapping("/myName")
    public String myName() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    int i = 0;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000L)
    public void scheduled() {
        System.err.println(++i + "-" + pageSize);
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my application.yml file:

```
taco:
  orders:
    pageSize: fifty
```

This print fine "fifty". But when I go to terminal and set a different value for the key, that new value is not reflected.

```
export TACO_ORDERS_PAGESIZE=NINETY
```

I have also created a [git repo](https://github.com/farazdurrani/SpringBoot_ConfigurationProperties_NotWorking) if somebody wants to retry it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248066/how-to-reload-properties-with-spring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload properties with Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248066/how-to-reload-properties-with-spring)

Answer (score 2):

You need to substitute the environment variable in your yaml file.

```
taco: 
     orders: 
        pageSize: {TACO_ORDERS_PAGESIZE : fifty}
```

The default value for your `taco.orders.pageSize` is fifty it will be automatically override by your env variable `TACO_ORDERS_PAGESIZE` NINETY.

Comment: It is not working. I am not passing those env variables when booting up the application. I am passing those env variables when the application is already running. I don't want to rebuild and redeploy the application. I want to change those env variables dynamically during runtime.

Comment: I think for this you may need to refer @RefreshScope logic.
Refer : https://andressanchezblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/15/refresh-scope-in-spring-cloud/